# Custom alert in indicator

Tags: alert, trading, pine-script-v5, indicator

I want code that alert in ll when just cross hl and alert hh when just cross lh
note : I don't need alert LH or HL HH(cross HH) and LL(cross LL)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Not sure. try this approach.

```
    alertcondition(long_final, title="buy alarm", message="buy signal!!!")
    alertcondition(short_final, title="sell alarm", message="sell 
    signal!!!")
    last_signal := long_final ? 1 : short_final ? -1 : last_signal[1]
    plotshape(long_final, style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.belowbar, color=green,size=size.tiny,title="buy
    label",text="BUY",textcolor=white)
    plotshape(short_final, style=shape.labeldown,
```